# Prove $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^{b_{n}} = e^{c}$ where $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{b_{n}}{n}=c$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I want to prove $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{b_{n}} = e^{c}$ where $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{b_{n}}{n}=c$.

I tried doing it with epsilons but I want to find some kind of argument that doesn't require this type of proof. So I want help with that.

Thanks in advance for anyone who helps.

Comment: Note that $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{b_{n}}=\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right]^\frac{b_{n}}n$$

Comment: Use the fact that for any $\epsilon>0$, we have $N$ such that for any $n>N$, $n(1-\epsilon)<b_n<n(1+\epsilon)$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Maybe closer https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3290296/505767?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Comment: @user:Indeed, thanks for looking for a more suitable duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

(Since it was answered in the comment, and I don't think I deserve the reputation gained with this one, I'll post this as a community wiki.)

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1+\frac 1 n \right)^{b_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left[ \left(1+\frac 1 n\right)^n \right]^{\frac {b_n}{n}} = \exp\left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{b_n}{n} \right) = \exp(c)=e^c.$

Comment: I think you meant to have $(1+\frac1n)^{b_n}=\exp\Big(\frac{b_n}{n}\log\big((1+\frac1n)^n\big)\Big)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow}\exp(c\log e)=e^c$

Comment: @OliverDíaz The answer arguably just uses the continuity of $(x,y) \mapsto x^y$ in a neighborhood of $(e,c)$.

Comment: Indeed I would say simply  by continuity $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{b_{n}}=\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right]^\frac{b_{n}}n \to e^c$$ I don't like this  $$\ldots = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left[ \left(1+\frac 1 n\right)^n \right]^{\frac {b_n}{n}} = \exp\left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{b_n}{n} \right) = \ldots$$ in which we take the limit in two steps. As an alternative what suggested by Oliver Diaz is also fine.